# Not able to run appium tests using mvn commands

Tags: android, maven, selenium, automation, appium

When I run any of my tests via `testNG` in **IntelliJ Idea** everything is OK. But if I want to run a test using `maven` command, e.g `mvn clean test`, 1)Session is restarted for 2-3 times. By "restaryed" I mean 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5uz7.png)
2)and  then I get following error after my first try of using a driver:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Here are my capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME.toString(), "Nexus 5");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION.toString(), "8.0.0");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME.toString(), "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT.toString(), "1000000");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.APP.toString(), new File(config.getTestedAppPath()).getAbsolutePath());`
```

Creating Appium driver:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: You're not clear in your original post or your answer to the suggested responses - Are you -manually- launching the appium server or do you start the server with your code?  It's been a while since I've tried running tests from maven, but I seem to recall the syntax being `mvn -dtest`

Comment: I launch appium server manually

Answer (score 0):

It seems like appium server not started.

Start appium on terminal or start it from appium's desktop application.

Comment: How could I run test via testNG if appium was not started? Appium Server is started when i run tests

Answer (score 0):

İf you use real device, you should just click the Start Server button

[image]

Else, you should write 127.0.0.1 for the host.

Comment: I use an emulator and i use 127.0.0.1 for the host